# Async action without chaining promise to actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a problem using `componentWillReceiveProps` with redux async action, below is my code and explanation.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.job.status === 'applied'){
    this.showAppliedDialog()
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchJob(this.props.match.params.id)
}
```

Requirements: 
when user clicked on the applied button
- change user's job status to 'applied'
- show a dialog of 'thank you for the application' to notify to user

Bug:
After user's job status is applied, he revisit the route or refresh on the current route,
the dialog of 'thank you for the application' is shown.

Expected:
Do not show 'thank you for the application' dialog

I solve above issue with the callback approach. But is this the only way to do it? I would like to use reducer instead of 
keep returning my async dispatch and do it a callback way

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchJob(this.props.match.params.id)
  .then(resp => resp.status === 'applied' && this.showAppliedDialog())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.job.status === 'applied' && this.props.job.status !== 'applied'){
    this.showAppliedDialog()
  }
}
```

By doing this, dialog will be shown only while changing the status to 'applied', it wont show dialog if already status is applied.

Comment: what if it's a redirect instead of a dialog? do I have to do multiple condition checking to redirect the user to other page like above too?

Comment: `nextProps.job.status != this.props.jobs.status` may also work (I use the logic at work to detect prop changes)

Comment: @JamieAden even if it is redirect this logic will work, however for a redirect you are better of redirecting on success of your ajax call to update status.

Comment: @SterlingArcher yup that works as well. But that condition will be true for other status as well, not only applied.

Comment: looks like `nextProps.job.status === 'applied' && this.props.job.status !== 'applied'` is not very descriptive, how about `nextProps.job.status !== this.props.jobs.status && nextProps.job.state === 'applied'`?

Comment: @Subin why is it redirect is not recommend to put in componentWillRecieveProps?